# lower_bound for vector<MyClass*>

Tags: c++, vector, lower-bound

I have this simple class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int id;
    string name;

};
```

I want to have a vector with pointers to objects of this class that is sorted by the referenced `MyClass` `id`. I thought that using `lower_bound` would be easy, I did it before with vectors of objects (not pointers). With objects, I overloaded `operator<` like that:

```
bool operator<(MyClass left, int right) {
    return (left.id < right);
}
```

Then I used `lower_bound` to insert new `MyClass` object to sorted vector.

```
vector<MyClass>::iterator low;
low = lower_bound(vectorname.begin(),vectorname.end(),id);
prP = idContainer.begin();
prP = idContainer.insert(low, newobject);
```

I am lost how to do the same with the vector of `MyClass` pointers. Can anyone help me achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two overloads of [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );

template< class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare >
ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp );
```

The first one is the one you used for your `vector<MyClass>`, it uses `operator<` by default. The second one allows for a custom comparison function which takes an element from the container as the first argument and the value as the second. That's what you want to use for your `vector<MyClass*>`:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> pvec;
auto low = std::lower_bound(pvec.begin(), pvec.end(), id,
    [](const MyClass* c, const MyClass& id) {
        return *c < id;
    });
```

It's a little odd that the comparison takes two arguments of different types, but that's just how it is.

Note: your current `operator<` takes its arguments by *value*. That incurs unnecessary copies. You'll want to change that to take them by reference to `const`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the comparison function doesn't need to have the same type for both parameters.